# what is the formula to calculate $dX_t$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

If $X_t= e^{W_t}g(t)$ where $W_t$ is an Wiener process and $g(t)\in C^2[0,\infty)$, could any one tell me what is the formula to calculate $dX_t$? Thanks so much.

what about if $Y_t= \sqrt{X_t}$?, the same formuale to find $dY_t$?

Comment: use Ito's formula with the formula $f(x,t) =g(t) e^{x}.$

Comment: Thanks done............

Comment: what about if $Y_t= \sqrt{X_t}$?, the same formuale to find $dY_t$?

Comment: I mean what will be $f(x,t)$ In this case?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}.$

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssss